# Should a notification be sent to chat room owners when someone requests access?

Tags: feature-request, chat, notifications

I created a private chat room recently for some discussions about a community event some users had expressed interest in collaborating on. I then posted a link to the room in a meta post discussing the event. A few people requested access to the room, but I never got a notification that they had requested access. It wasn't until one of them pinged me in a comment to the meta post and told me that they had requested access that I found out. Is this normal?

If the room were a gallery room, instead of private, would I have gotten a notification when someone requested write access?

If so, I propose that a notification should be sent to chat room owners whenever someone requests (write) access to rooms (either private or gallery).

Comment: Do you really mean *private*?  If so, how were the other users able to request access?  Do you mean you created a *gallery* room, where anybody can see but only those with access can post?  Please edit to clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, Maybe I didn't go about things the right way when creating the room? I did create it as a private room (not gallery), but the intended use for the room was to enable a few of us (not just mods) to chat about a community event. I then posted a link to the room on the meta discussion about the event and added those who indicated they were interested. Apparently a few others simply requested access. Maybe this should have been a gallery room? I'll update the question some.

Answer (score 2):

Private rooms are for moderation-related purposes only, most sites have just one single moderator chat room. Typically, only moderators (and SE employees) have access to those rooms, and this kind of access is implicitly granted by the diamond, and not explicitly via the room access list.

The cases where users that aren't a moderator or SE employee should have access to a private room are very rare. Internal moderator discussions often contain information about users that regular users are not supposed to see, we are bound by the moderator agreement and are not allowed to reveal private user information.

If you create a private room, you should know who needs access. Just give every user that is not a moderator on the parent site of the room (and not an SE employee) access and then superping them. That is the easiest way to get everyone into one private room.

There is really not much use for the ability to request access to private rooms, this is more useful for gallery chat rooms.

Comment: @MonicaCellio if you have a direct link you can request access

Comment: @MadScientist I updated the question and posted some more details. Perhaps the room should have been a gallery room. Users can request write access to gallery rooms right? If they do, is a notification sent?

Comment: @mikeazo I'm not sure about gallery chat rooms, I never used them.