# Ability to ping chat room owners

Tags: feature-request, chat, ping, room-owner

A recurring hassle in chat is to get a hold of a room owner when something needs their attention.

As a crude workaround, some rooms have separate guidelines for users with an explanation of how to *maybe* find a room owner who is active in chat and pingable; but even in the best of worlds, this is tedious, and sometimes simply not possible.

In some more detail, you have to visit the room's info page, and from there prioritize which of the room owners might be receptive to a ping. Sometimes they have not been online in chat for a long time, sometimes they are active in chat but in the middle of something else, and sometimes they are busy just now but able to respond to your ping after you have needlessly hassled several other room owners when they were not able to get back to you immediately.

My proposal, then, is simple: Please provide **a mechanism by which we can reach *all* room owners,** simultaneously, or in a way which otherwise allows them to coordinate their response. Perhaps something like `@:RO` to use a vaguely intuitive syntax which however will not currently ping any actual users.

Related:

- [Notify room owners when a user is kicked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247203/notify-room-owners-when-a-user-is-kicked) [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) mechanism for reaching room owners with a banner when a user is kicked;
- [Add pingable groups to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280915/add-pingable-groups-to-chat) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) a much broader proposal for allowing room owners to create pingable groups in general;
- [Should a notification be sent to chat room owners when someone requests access?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240674/should-a-notification-be-sent-to-chat-room-owners-when-someone-requests-access) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) tangentially requests another type of room owner notification

The banner in the answer to the first question might actually be a good implementation which uses existing UI and conventions. Then the banner could disappear once the ping is handled by one of the room owners, too, I imagine. But let's not dictate what exactly the solution should look like.

I realize that chat is not getting a lot of love these days, but that could change. I'm hoping when that happens, this could be considered.

Comment: So in essence this would need to somewhat resemble a flag dashboard for room owners, so that once the ping has been dealt with, it can also be cleared for all other room owners, as not to needlessly bring them to chat.

Comment: If something is so urgent you need all room owners to rush to the room, better raise a flag, RO power is very very limited anyway.

Comment: Usually I don't, and that's why I am asking for a mechanism which would let the collective of room owners coordinate between them. The banner idea proposed by @Luuklag sounds like a nice proposal, for example.

Comment: One common use case is when in SOCVR you post a `cv-pls` but then the OP updates their question. Unfortunately, some users of the room will still proceed to click on the question as long as the `cv-pls` is up, and so you would like for it to be removed expediently. However, there is a bunch of room owners and several of them are mods who tend to be _reachable_ but by no means always _responsive_ to pings. Another common use case would be when a rude user is harassing the room and needs to be dealt with by whoever happens to be awake and at their keyboard.

Comment: SOCVR might be a bad example. The ROs keep getting elected as moderators, making mod flags an increasingly reasonable way of contacting a RO. ;-)